# Select one OR another name but don't select third - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Need your help, can't find the solution with selecting two strings from the database but the third one NOT (to not show Bob is the problem). Tnx!

```
select username, fname, lname
from customer
where lower(lname) = 'Masa'
or lower(lname) = 'Blue'
where not fname = 'Bob';
```

Comment: First off, the term "lower(lname) = 'Masa'" will _never_ be true, because your literal 'Masa' is not itself lower case.  The 'lower' function returns a value with _all_ of the characters in lower-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `in`:

```
select username, fname, lname
from customer
where lower(lname) in ('masa', 'blue') and
      fname <> 'Bob';
```

Note:  SQL has an operator for "not equals":  `<>`.

You are using `lower()` but the comparison values have upper case characters, so they will never match.  If you want an exact match:

```
where lname in ('Masa', 'Blue') and
      fname <> 'Bob';
```

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are critical when mixing OR and AND operators. AFAIK, Oracle comparison is case-sensitive so converting all characters to lowercase will not match the criteria. If you need to insure case sensitivity is ignored, then convert data to lower or upper case and use the corresponding criteria.

Consider:

```
WHERE (Lower(lname) = 'masa' OR Lower(lname) = 'blue') AND Lower(fname) <> 'bob'
```

So if Masa happens to have first name of Bob, record will be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use parenthesis for first two conditions since the third condition should be obeyed independent of first two conditions.
Then since you used lower(), your provided name strings should be in lower case or those will always fail the condition.

```
select username, fname, lname
from customer
where (lower(lname) = 'masa' or lower(lname) = 'blue') and lower(fname)<> 'bob';
```